# How can I raise the maximum upload file size?

Tags: 8, webforms

I set up private file directory at /var/www/private to keep upload files from webform and setup permission on directory and files (664 for files, 775 for directories). When I click on upload button and select file, it throw an exception -

 **"An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (32 MB) that this server supports."**

Solution is running on Drupal 8.3 on VM (Vagrant). Below is screen capture of error message

[image: Upload file error message]

Appreciate if you have an answer of this bug

Answer (score 0):

This is not particular to the Drupal site but is caused by the hosting (local Vagrant) environment's PHP configuration.

Try increasing these values in php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M 
post_max_size = 64M 
memory_limit = 64M
```

**NOTE**: If you are using Webform for anonymous file upload to your site and you are setting high limits on file size like this you are quickly going to fill up a lot of disk space (most likely with spam).

**NOTE**: After modifying php.ini file(s), you need to restart your HTTP server to use new configuration

See answer on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size).

Comment: After resize post_max_size = 64M, its throw same exception. The values in php.ini: memory_limit = 192M, upload_max_filesize = 64M, and post_max_size = 64. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Now I got this error "An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (64 MB) that this server supports." I select few kilobyte size of file but showing exceeded 64 MB. There must be a bug on webform. When I navigate private directory 'var/www/private' I saw there are subfolders created by application 'var/www/private/webform/formname/_sid_/. I wonder whats made  exceeded 64 MB when the file size is just few kilobytes. Appreciate if you share your experience. Thank you

Comment: @Bhagi have you resolved this problem? I'm in the same situation

Comment: Same issue with me

Comment: If you have restarted your webserver the new values should load, but some hosts limit access to changing these settings. Try confirming that your changes have "taken" by getting the output of `ini_get ('upload_max_filesize')` and the others.